# Passing an array to Laravel Blade Directive

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to avoid doing the following in blade

```
<?php if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRoles(['administrator', 'superadmin'])) { ?>
...
<?php } ?>
```

I tried a blade directive like this;

```
Blade::directive('roles', function ($roles) {
        return "<?php if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRoles({$roles}): ?>";
    });
```

I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':' (View: /Users/.../index.blade.php)
```

When I try this in laravel blade;

```
@roles(['admin', 'super-admin'])
...
@endroles
```

I want to pass an array of roles in blade and have the right permissions executed. I do have a method on the User model called hasRoles(array $roles) that accepts an array of roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a '**:**' at the end of your if condition

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRoles({$roles}):
```

change it to

```
if ( auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRoles({$roles}) ) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you @Digvijay, I thought I already tried this. It worked!